# Is there a way to force Visual Studio 2005 to use the Framework v3.5 C# compiler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to compile some code that targets .NET v3.5 in Visual Studio 2005.

I suppose I could download the 2008 Express Editions... do I need both Visual Web Developer AND C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not.  That (framework targeting) is a feature that was introduced in VS2008.

To answer your second question that depends. If this is solely a Website/Web Application then you would not need the C# Express. If this is an application/service/etc, then you would need the C# Express.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom MSBuild script to do your builds, making sure that you use latest MSBuild tool. (You still could not build from within Visual Studio though) You are going to have all kinds of problems using VS2005 to build .NET 3.5 apps so I'd recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this applies to VS2005 due to Stephen Wrightons answer but i remember that when you create a new project, to the top right of the dialog box that appears there is a drop down box to select the version of the framework you want to use.

Comment: Nope - only applies to VS2008 and VS2010

Comment: My apologies, i couldnt remember which version it was =/